# Which values of c give dependent columns in this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know it's a simple question and I have no idea how to solve it.

Which values of $c$ give dependent columns (combination equals zero)?

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
c & c & c \\ 
2 & 1 & 5 \\ 
3 & 3 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Cheers.

Comment: Are you sure the values are correct? I don't think this has a solution

Comment: @Marcel trivially, if $c=0$ the top row will be entirely zero, implying rank will be at most two, implying dependent columns.  The question is then if there are any others and why or why not.

Comment: sorry, I meant a non-trivial solution.

Comment: Compute the determinant of this matrix, it will be a cubic function of $c$. Then find the roots of this cubic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the number of linearly independent columns in a matrix is equal to the rank of the matrix which is in turn the number of pivot points in the row-echelon form of the matrix.  You may attempt to row-reduce the matrix.

This is tedious to do, so let us instead find the determinant of the matrix.

The determinant of a square matrix will be zero if and only if the columns are linearly dependent.

We find $\det(A)=c(6-15)-c(12-15)+c(6-3)=-3c$ which will equal zero if and only if $c=0$

If curious on how to approach via the row reduction argument, break it into cases.  In the case that $c=0$, it is clear to see that since there is a zero row that after row reduction you will have at most two pivots.  You will find that it will row reduce to $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&3\\0&1&-1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$, but this was unnecessary information and time could be saved by not doing so.

In the case that $c\neq 0$, you may use as your first step, dividing the first row by $c$.  (**note: this step is not allowed without first specifying that $c\neq 0$ and considering that case separately as we did here.** *If you were to incorrectly divide by $c$ while it is still unknown, you would mistakenly find that the columns are independent regardless the value of $c$*)

In doing so, you have the matrix $\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\2&1&5\\3&3&6\end{bmatrix}$ which will row reduce to $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

These again imply that when $c=0$ the columns will be dependent and when $c\neq 0$ the columns will be linearly independent.